# DropDownList No Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm sure this is pretty simple (been up all night with teething daughter!) my drop down list is always returning 0:

```
<p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectVenue" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="small-dropdownlist" DataTextField="SiteName" DataValueField="SiteName" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="-- select --" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
```

Here's the code that populates it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dArray.Length; i++)
{
    ddlSelectVenue.Items.Add(new ListItem(dArray[i]["SiteName"].ToString(),dArray[i]["SiteName"].ToString()));
}
```

It does contain values, here's a snippet of the page source:

```
<select name="ctl00$ddlSelectVenue" id="ctl00_ddlSelectVenue" class="small-dropdownlist">
<option value="0">-- select --</option>
<option value="Admiral Duncan - London">Admiral Duncan - London</option>
<option value="Anchor - Bristol">Anchor - Bristol</option>
<option value="Assembly - Preston">Assembly - Preston</option>
</select>
```

Here's the Go button HTML:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imbGo" ImageUrl="~/img/GoButton.png" OnClick="imbGo_Click" runat="server" />
```

And here is the imbGo_Click (well part of it):

```
protected void imbGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(ddlSelectVenue.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "Admiral Duncan - London":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.welovetolisten.co.uk?unitcode=5004&FROMWEBSITE=1");
            break;
        case "Anchor - Bristol":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.welovetolisten.co.uk?unitcode=3010&FROMWEBSITE=1");
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

It's always bombing to default: as I said it's probably obvious why, but I'm just not seeing it!

**EDIT**

I've solved it using this, but I will accept the first person who said about posting back as that was the issue, what I don't understand is I have use drop down lists that have been populated on PageLoad before and not had this sort of problem.

Anyway, I have set a cookie on the drop down list changing using jQuery instead:

```
$('.small-dropdownlist').change(function () {
            var info = $('.small-dropdownlist option:selected').text();
            $.cookie("FeedbackVenue", info);
        });
```

Then read the cookie in on the Go button:

```
if(Request.Cookies["FeedbackVenue"] != null)
        {
            venue = Request.Cookies["FeedbackVenue"].Value;
        }

        switch(venue.Replace("%20"," "))
```

Now it works.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: When & Where is populate code executing, which event ?

Comment: Does it work if you databound the dropdownlist instead of adding the items programmatically? `ddlSelectVenue.DataSource = dArray; ddlSelectVenue.DataBind();`. You have set already the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`.

Comment: It is posting back on autoPostBack - even though !IsPostBack is in the page load when binding the pubs, how to solve I wonder?

Comment: I'm confused, it's just not picking up the Drop Down List value, I've remove the Response.Redirect for now, the value is always emtpy when you click the Go button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you do not rebind DropDownList on PostBack and look at this article http://evonet.com.au/dropdownlist1-has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-list-of-items/

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do not rebind `DropDownList` on `PostBack`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you databound the dropdownlist instead of adding the items programmatically?

```
ddlSelectVenue.DataSource = dArray;
```

You have set already the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. However, i add it too if someone misses it:

```
ddlSelectVenue.DataTextField="SiteName";
ddlSelectVenue.DataValueField="SiteName";

ddlSelectVenue.DataBind();
```

You must also ensure that the dropdownlist is not refilled on every postback since that would prevent events and all changes/selections will be undone.

So (e.g. in `Page_Load`):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    // DataBindDropDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you put your commands to populate the drop down list?

I do

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.ddlSelectVenue.Items.Add(new ListItem("Admiral Duncan - London", "Admiral Duncan - London"));
            }
        }
```

And then, on my button click event i have

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = this.ddlSelectVenue.SelectedValue;
        }
```

The value is equal to "Admiral Duncan - London"